# Change Nprogress bar location

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am running one mvc 4 application where i have navbar in my layout.cshtml page.
I recently added N

```html
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Apps/nprogress.js")"></script>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/nprogress.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    NProgress.start();
    setTimeout(function () { NProgress.done(); $('.fade').removeClass('out'); }, 4000);
</script>
<div style="padding-top:50px">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">

            </div>

        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

progress from [here](https://github.com/rstacruz/nprogress) for one of my view to show progress bar when page loads.
in that view i have one div. When i run my application progress bar is showing up of navbar. But i wanted to show progress bar below of the div. How would i achieve the same?

I got some idea from [Github Nprogress](https://github.com/rstacruz/nprogress#parent) where i found this [image]

But don't know where do i set this code?

Answer (score 0):

As i mentioned above code NProgress.configure that needs to put very first of your script which has been used in your page, And change parent id to your div or container in which element you want to show the progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

For a better control of NProgress appearence, you can change the markup using template. To keep the progress bar working, keep an element with role='bar' in there. See the default template for reference.

```
NProgress.configure({
  template: "<div class='....'>...</div>"
});
```

More details at https://github.com/rstacruz/nprogress#template